# How to get date in react native from Firestore?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display date from Firestore in react native in dd/mm/yyyy format.
I have set date from another screen
here is code of screen1 from where I set date:

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("date");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === "ios");
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode("date");
  };
return (
    <View
      style={{
        marginTop: "15%",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
      }}>
 <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Select Date" />
      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
            alignContent: "center",
            width: "50%",
            marginLeft: "20%",
            marginTop: "8%",
          }}
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={mode}
          is24Hour={true}
          display="default"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
<Button
title:'save'
onPress:{
           dbRef.doc().set({
              title: date,
              sub: service,
              key: new Date(),
            });}/>
```

here is how I am retrieving data in screen2

```
<FlatList
          ListEmptyComponent={<Text>Nothing Available</Text>}
          style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#D8E0E5E6" }}
          data={exampleState}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Card
              title={item.title.seconds.toString()}
              sub={item.sub}
              // onPress={() => {}}
            />
          )}
        />
```

what I am seeing is this [image] basically time in seconds and I want it in dd/mm/yyyy format
screenshot of Firestore [image]

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format the date you get from `firestore`:

```js
<FlatList
          ListEmptyComponent={<Text>Nothing Available</Text>}
          style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#D8E0E5E6" }}
          data={exampleState}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Card
              title={new Date(item.title).toLocaleString()}
              sub={item.sub}
              // onPress={() => {}}
            />
          )}
        />
```

For other formatting options use libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Then you can just use something like this:

```js
<FlatList
          ListEmptyComponent={<Text>Nothing Available</Text>}
          style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#D8E0E5E6" }}
          data={exampleState}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Card
              title={moment(item.title).format('YYYY.MM.DD')}
              sub={item.sub}
              // onPress={() => {}}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Comment: Hey @Tarik Huber Thanks for replying. I applied what you said but getting Invalid date as the outcome.

Comment: I solved it by using moment in screen1 from where I upload date.

Comment: Consider when uploading the date alread formated that you could get in trouble if your App is used in different time zones. I would rather recommend to use moment as shown in the secon part of the answer when displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did while setting date to Firestore in screen1

```
<Button
title:'save'
onPress:{
           dbRef.doc().set({
              title: moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY"),
              sub: service,
              key: new Date(),
            });}/>
```